# Drupal 5.x migrate content from one type to another

Tags: drupal, content-management, drupal-5

I have a bunch of content in the page content type that I would like to migrate to a new custom content type. I don't need to add or remove fields or change the data stored in the content type at all, just straight copy them over. Is there a module to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like the iPhone, "there's a module for that." [Node Convert](http://drupal.org/project/node_convert) does this quickly and easily.